# Execute electron packager from node express route

Tags: node.js, electron, electron-packager

I’m not able to find much info on this however I know that I can create an electron app via the command prompt `electron-packager .`. However is it possible to execute it front end via a node express route?

So I'd like to do something like this:

```
router.get('/downloadGame/', async function(req, res) {
    var dirPath = "../game/src";

// Run electron packager here against this folder
// And then zip it up

await res.zip({
    files: [{
        path: dirPath,
        name: 'Package'
    }],
    filename: 'Package.zip'
});
```

});

Answer (score 1):

I don't think Electron Packager can be used programmatically. I didn't find any relevant information in the documentation. However, I think you could use Node.js' [`child_process.exec()` function](https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html#child_process_child_process_exec_command_options_callback) to run the command like you are used to (considering that Electron Packager is installed on the server).

You could also use another library [Electron Builder](https://www.electron.build/api/electron-builder) that offers such functionality.

Comment: Thanks! I'm just looking it up, is there a way of creating a single exe file with electron builder?

Comment: Also I'm having problems finding any documentation on how to run Electron Builder from within node express

Comment: for the exe file yes, I am doing it for Mockoon, you can see the CI pipeline here with the commands: https://github.com/mockoon/mockoon/blob/master/.github/workflows/binaries-build.yml#L89-L119
But I am not using Electron Builder programmatically, you can find more info there: https://www.electron.build/api/electron-builder